# How is called when someone carries his birth city as surname?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Sometimes history figures are called by its birth city as surname. Example: Milon of Croton, Thales of Miletus.

How is this called in English? Is this an Epithet?

Comment: "of *place* " is not a surname, but an indicative that that a person belongs to that particular place. Whereas, in Kathy Ireland "Ireland" is a toponymic surname.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** [epithet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet) since that is an adjective added to a person's name or a phrase used instead of it, usually to criticize or praise them:

So epithet could be used for Richard the lionhearted (Richard Cœur de Lion)

However epithet is one form of by-name and another form is nobiliary particle

If he was also known as Richard **lord of Aquitaine** amongst many other titles.

and this is known as a [**nobiliary particle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobiliary_particle)
however those peers of lower status may receive a [Territorial designation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_designation)

and  the burgher class could have a non-nobiliary

> [Toponymic surname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toponymic_surname)